# how to group object elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and broke my head with this task. Can anyone please help me to find a solution to this task: Each employee receives a salary for the completed transaction.
Each transaction has a specific date.
It is necessary to group employees by specific dates.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 111,
    name: "Ivan",
    salary: 1000,
    date: "2020-01-01",
  },
  {
    id: 222,
    name: "Oleg",
    salary: 2000,
    date: "2020-01-01",
  },
  {
    id: 333,
    name: "Maks",
    salary: 3000,
    date: "2020-01-01",
  },
  {
    id: 444,
    name: "Anya",
    salary: 4000,
    date: "2020-01-02",
  },
];

// Example of answer:
obj = {
  "2020-01-01": {
    111: {
      salary: 10000,
    },
    // ... another people
  },
  // ... another days
};
```

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Array.reduce()` should work in this case:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 111,
    name: "Ivan",
    salary: 1000,
    date: "2020-01-01",
  },
  {
    id: 222,
    name: "Oleg",
    salary: 2000,
    date: "2020-01-01",
  },
  {
    id: 333,
    name: "Maks",
    salary: 3000,
    date: "2020-01-01",
  },
  {
    id: 444,
    name: "Anya",
    salary: 4000,
    date: "2020-01-02",
  },
];
console.log(arr.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
  // Check if the date is present in the array.
  if (!acc[cur.date]) {
    // If not, initialise an empty object.
    acc[cur.date] = {};
  }
  // Inside that object add the date with the current element.
  acc[cur.date][cur.id] = {... cur};
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

---

This gives me an output of:

```
{
  "2020-01-01": {
    "111": {
      "id": 111,
      "name": "Ivan",
      "salary": 1000,
      "date": "2020-01-01"
    },
    "222": {
      "id": 222,
      "name": "Oleg",
      "salary": 2000,
      "date": "2020-01-01"
    },
    "333": {
      "id": 333,
      "name": "Maks",
      "salary": 3000,
      "date": "2020-01-01"
    }
  },
  "2020-01-02": {
    "444": {
      "id": 444,
      "name": "Anya",
      "salary": 4000,
      "date": "2020-01-02"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Comrade I am so happy I was able to help you.